# convert .xlsx file to .xls(97-2003) workbook C#

Tags: c#, excel, iis, model-view-controller, converters

i am trying to convert .xlsx file to .xls(97-2003) workbook. which might have around 1000 rows n more . is there any nuget package that i can use which is free? i have tried using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but it didnt work out on IIS.

```
    string sourceFileName = appSettings.ImageDirectory + "Report.xlsx";
    string DestFileName = appSettings.ImageDirectory + "Report.xls";
    object oMissing = Type.Missing;
    var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(sourceFileName, oMissing, oMissing,
                                    oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, 
    oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, 
    oMissing);
    wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
    wb.SaveAs(DestFileName , 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    app.Quit();
    string fullPath = appSettings.ReportFolderPath + "/Report.xls"; 
    return Json(new { path = fullPath, errorMessage = "" });
```

Comment: _"but it didnt work out on IIS"_ - what actually happened?

Comment: Showing the code you tried would also help get a reply. Note that asking for library recommendations is a reason for closing the question.

Comment: @PaulF I got this error

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file path\Report.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: Have you checked the file does exist at that location and that you do have the appropriate permissions to access a file at that location.

Comment: Also have you tried using Google - this query _"c# excel free library"_  brings up several pages listing libraries which claim to do what you want as well as a question or two on SO that suggest libraries.

Comment: yes the file was there on the path

Comment: And do you have both read & write access to that folder?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,  you couldn't use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` on a server where Excel is not installed.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll is just a translator (called an Interop Assembly) to help you talk to Excel.

You could try to use [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) to achieve your requirement.

Comment: i have tried using ClosedXML works with Excel 2007/2010 (OpenXML) files i.e .xlsx and .xls  is not supported by ClosedXML.

Comment: If you still want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, you could try to install the excel.

Comment: not particular about Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel , but it ll better if i could use a free nuget package